# Explanation of grid search CV parameter grid for pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

What means this `'feature_selection__k': list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))` code in:

```
param_grid = [{
    'preparation__num__imputer__strategy': ['mean', 'median', 'most_frequent'],
    'feature_selection__k': list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))
}]

grid_search_prep = GridSearchCV(prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline, param_grid, cv=5,
                                scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=2)
grid_search_prep.fit(housing, housing_labels)
```

where

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
        ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs),
    ])
```

and

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ])
```

Can you please explain every step in line `'feature_selection__k': list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))`?

---

If all code is needed it is here: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb  . The code part that I am asking about is at the bottom of notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `GridSearchCV` here is not applied to a simple estimator, but to a pipeline:

```
prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', full_pipeline),
    ('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k)),
    ('svm_reg', SVR(**rnd_search.best_params_))
])
```

where

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
        ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs),
    ])
```

and

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ])
```

the `param_grid` needs to be organized into "levels", so that it knows what exact parameters of the constituent pipelines components it will access.

So here, the `feature_selection` part of the string refers to the respective part of the `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline`, and `k` to the respective parameter of the `TopFeatureSelector`. Levels are separated by a double underscore `__`, so to access the parameter `k` of the `TopFeatureSelector` the respective parameter is defined as `feature_selection__k`.

For the same reason, in order for `param_grid` to access the `strategy` parameter of the `SimpleImputer`, the respective entry is `'preparation__num__imputer__strategy'`, i.e.:

- the `preparation` part of the first-level `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline`
- the `num` part of the second-level `full_pipeline`
- the `imputer` part of the third-level `num_pipeline`
- the parameter `strategy` of the `SimpleImputer`

each entry, as already said, separated by a double underscore `__`.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))` returns a list of integers from 1 to n, where n is length of `feature_importances`.

For example if the length of `feature_importances` is 5.

```
list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))
```

will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You need to add "+ 1" because range excludes the upper bound.

Comment: What `feature_selection__k` part means? Is it just arbitrary string?

Comment: It's a list which enables the search from 1 to n